# 90 percentile response time

Tags: splunk

I want to plot 90 percentile response time on splunk. Is the below correct?

```
| timechart p90(ResponseTime)
```

or is the below correct

```
eventstats avg(ResponseTime) as ttavg | eventstats p90(ttavg) as p90avg | timechart max(p90avg)
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

The first is simpler and more straightforward and will get the job done.

Use `eventstats` when you need the statistic you are calculating added as a field onto each event. You might want to do this if you want to perform a further calculation using that statistic.